# Google Spreadsheets vlookup in conditional formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need to highlight some values in a given range to match a label returned from a vlookup function, like this: `VLOOKUP(ADDRESS(ROW();COL();4);INDIRECT("<sheet>!A:D");4;0)="<label>"`.

I've already checked the ranges and I've tested the function in a stand-alone cell (and it worked); however it doesn't seem to work on the conditional formatting tool.

Comment: Post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the function you have provided. It worked when I expanded the range under "Apply to Range". I made the following test case just to be sure:

[image: setup1]

With the following Conditional Format Rules setup & modified function:

```
=VLOOKUP(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4),INDIRECT("Test!A:D"),4,0)="testLabel1"
```

[image: setup2]

I used the range A:D in this test case just to test out the function.